# Get state of checkbox cellWidget in QTableWidget PyQT

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtablewidget, qcheckbox

I work on python plugin for QGIS. In this plugin I have created a QTableWidget with 3 columns. These columns are QCheckbox, QTableWidgetItem and QComboBox. I would like to retrieve the values contained in these 3 columns. For the moment I managed to get the values of QComboBox and QTableWidgetItem but I can't seem to get the value of the QCheckBox.

```
liste = ['Carte 1','Carte 2','Carte 3','Carte 4','Carte 5','Carte 6']
        combo_box_options = ["A4 Paysage","A4 Portrait", "A3 Paysage","A3 Portrait"]
        self.dlg_format = Dialog_format()
        self.dlg_format.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(liste))

        for index in range(len(liste)):
            item = QTableWidgetItem(liste[index])
            self.dlg_format.tableWidget.setItem(index, 1, item)
            self.dlg_format.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(0, 20)
            self.dlg_format.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1, 350)

            combo = QComboBox()
            for t in combo_box_options:
                combo.addItem(t)
            self.dlg_format.tableWidget.setCellWidget(index, 2, combo)

            widget = QWidget()
            checkbox = QCheckBox()
            checkbox.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)
            playout = QHBoxLayout(widget)
            playout.addWidget(checkbox)
            playout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            playout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
            widget.setLayout(playout)
            self.dlg_format.tableWidget.setCellWidget(index, 0, widget)

        self.dlg_format.show()
        result = self.dlg_format.exec_()

        if result:
            for index in range(len(liste)):
                text = self.dlg_format.tableWidget.item(index, 1).text()
                format = self.dlg_format.tableWidget.cellWidget(index, 2).currentText()
                check = self.dlg_format.tableWidget.cellWidget(index, 0).checkState() #Does not work
```

Comment: You are not adding the QCheckBox as cell widget, but a QWidget that contains it (which obviously doesn't have a `checkState()` property. Is that parent QWidget required?

Comment: Yes this parent is required because it permit to align the checkbox in the center of the cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QWidget is what is set as cell widget, not the checkbox, and that widget obviously has no `checkState` attribute.

There are various possibilities for this scenario.

Make the checkbox an attribute of the widget:

```py
    widget = QWidget()
    widget.checkbox = QCheckBox()
    playout.addWidget(widget.checkbox)

    # ...
    check = self.dlg_format.tableWidget.cellWidget(index, 0).checkbox.checkState()
```

Make the checkbox's `checkState` function a reference of the widget (note: no parentheses!) so that you can access it with the existing `cellWidget(index, 0).checkState()`:

```py
    checkbox = QCheckBox()
    widget.checkState = checkbox.checkState
```

Since all happens within the same scope (the function), you can totally ignore the `cellWidget` and use a list of tuples that contains the widgets:

```
    widgets = []
    for index in range(len(liste)):
        # ...
        widgets.append((item, combo, checkbox))
    # ...
    if result:
        for item, combo, checkbox in widgets:
            text = item.text()
            format = combo.currentText()
            check = checkbox.checkState()
```

Note that:

- [`checkState()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcheckbox.html#checkState)
  returns a [`Qt.CheckState`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#CheckState-enum) enum, which results in **2** (`Qt.Checked`) for a checked box; if you need a boolean, use [`isChecked()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#checked-prop) instead;
- you can use `enumerate` instead of `range`, since you are iterating through the list items anyway: `for index, text in enumerate(liste):`;
- if you don't need to add item data and the contents of the combo are always the same, just use `combo.addItems(combo_box_options)`;
- setting the column width for every cycle is pointless, just do it once outside the `for` loop;
- if you use `QHBoxLayout(widget)` there's no need for `widget.setLayout(playout)`, as the widget argument on a layout already sets that layout on the widget;
- instance attribute are created in order to make them persistent (it ensures that they are not garbage collected and allows future access); from your code it seems unlikely that you're going to use that dialog instance *after* that function returns, so making it a member of the instance (`self.dlg_format`) is unrequired and keeps resources unnecessarily occupied: the dialog would be kept in memory even after it's closed, and would be then deleted and overwritten as soon as it's created again; just make it a local variable (`dlg_format = Dialog_format()`);